# Keep variable references inside hashmap

Tags: android, memory-leaks

In `MONITOR` I can use profiler and see different variables by reference like this:
[image]

Is there a way to save these variable references (for instance, in hashmap) and delete all of them, when I need (imagining they are causing memory leak)

Comment: `Object.toString()` could be a solution. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

Comment: Not working. Any other ideas with examples? :)